# EF Core 5 code inheritance without database inheritance #26741

Tags: .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I have two EF models:

```
public class Child: BaseClass
{ 
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
}
```

```
[Table("TableName")]
public absctract class BaseClass
{
    public int ID {get; internal set;}
    ... some other properties and navigation collections...
}
```

I have only one table "TableName" with all columns from "BaseClass" and "Child" classes and I would use 'Child' type to access the table.
But, when i've tried to do it, i got exception: "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'."
With EF 6, I was able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Discriminator is how EF Core differentiates the .Net types in the hierarchy.

Check out the table per heirarchy section in these articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration
https://blogs.dhrutara.com/blogs/efcore5-migrations-with-inheritance/

Comment: I sure what Discriminator and TPH are. But in my case there isn't real inheritance - there is only one child type on base class per context and we don't need discriminator. I just trying to use common base class in differrent contexts to avoid copy-paste .